# python3 error using xlrd (I can't append list because error)

Tags: python-3.x, xlrd

```
import xlrd


def get_data(a):
    aa = worksheet.cell(a, 0).value
    bb = int(worksheet.cell(a, 2).value)
    cc = worksheet.cell(a, 3).value       

    return([aa,bb,cc])

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('d:/test.xls')
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

c = 1
objs = [] 

while worksheet.row(worksheet.nrows-1):
    f = get_data(c)
    objs.append(f)
    c = c + 1

print(objs)
```

I get the following error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "D:\test.py", line 20, in <module>
>   f = get_data(c)
> File "D:\test.py", line 6, in get_data
>   aa = worksheet.cell(a, 0).value
> File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\xlrd\sheet.py", line 399, in cell
>   self._cell_types[rowx][colx],
> IndexError: list index out of range
> ```

Comment: It is better to post the entire stack trace. The part you posted doesn't show in what line of your code the error was raised. I don't think the problem is appending to a list (and, BTW, pickle isn't relevant to anything shown here). Probably in your worksheet there is no data for column 0, 2, or 3 of one (or more) of the rows.

Comment: @dsh  there is data for column 0, 2, or 3  all, i delete pickle . but same error

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem now.  The error occurs when you call `get_data(c)`, and in that function it calls `worksheet.cell(a, 0)`.  While accessing column 0 of some row (the row number is not given in the error message), the index of either the row or column (or both) is greater than the data that exists.

Since the column number, `0`, is a constant, the greater question is on what row is it failing?  One way to approach debugging this is to catch the exception and log the row number.  For example:

```
try: 
    get_data(c)
except Exception as err:
    print("Failed to get data for row", c)
    raise
```

This change will tell you what row fails.

In reading your code more closely to try and determine the source of the row number, I see that your loop never ends.

> ```
> while worksheet.row(worksheet.nrows-1):
> ```

If the row object you retrieve is "truthy" then the loop will repeat.  Instead you want to check when your row number has reached the limit of rows in the file.  The most natural way to do this is with a 'for' loop.

```
for c in range(1, worksheet.nrows+1):
    f = get_data(c)
    objs.append(f)
```

This naturally makes the loop finite, and also eliminates two extra lines of code you have (no need to initialize or increment c).

Comment: i exchange simply follow your assident

Comment: `import xlrd



def get_data(a):    

    return([worksheet.cell(a, 0).value])

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('d:/test.xls')
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

c = 1
objs = [] 

for c in range(1, worksheet.nrows+1):
    try:
        f = get_data(c)
        objs.append(f)
        
    except Exception as err:
        print("Failed to get data for row", c)
        raise
    

print(objs)
`

Comment: `Failed to get data for row 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\test.py", line 17, in <module>
    f = get_data(c)
  File "D:\test.py", line 7, in get_data
    return([worksheet.cell(a, 0).value])
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\xlrd\sheet.py", line 399, in cell
    self._cell_types[rowx][colx],
IndexError: list index out of range`